# why TypeScript's typeof keyword just get the literal type?

Tags: typescript, covariance, control-flow, contravariance, union-types

here is some ts code:

```
type TopRoomInfoState = {
  loaded: false;
  loading: boolean;
  error: any;
  data: null;
} | {
  loaded: true;
  loading: boolean;
  error: any;
  data: GetTopRoomInfoRsp;
}

const inititalState: TopRoomInfoState = {
  loaded: false,
  loading: false,
  error: null,
  data: null,
};

type Test = typeof inititalState;
// but this `type Test` is merely the literal type of `const inititalState`
// not the whole union TopRoomInfoState ...
```

and why the `type Test` is the subset of the union TopRoomInfoState ?? how to make type Test is whole the union type ?

[image]

Comment: i guess it is because it evaluates `{
  loaded: false,
  loading: false,
  error: null,
  data: null,
}` if you append `as TopRoomInfoState` it will be as you expected.

Comment: yes, usage of as assertion works. i just want to know the inner principle

Comment: consider  `A= B | C`, let `a` be of  `A`, then `a` can be of `B` or `C`. Now think of `b` as `B`. Assign `b` to `a`. then a is of `B`. Proof: `typeof b` is `B` as `a` is(===) `b` => `typeof a` is `B`. Or let  `typeof a` be `A` then with `a === b` `typeof b` has to be `A`, but `b` cannot be `C` -> contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Because You have given Typescript hints that which one of the types forming `TopRoomInfoState` is your `initialState` variable.

If the `loaded` property of objects is `false` then your object is either of type

```
{
  loaded: false;
  loading: boolean;
  error: any;
  data: null;
}
```

or it's not of type `TopRoomInfoState` altogether. the same is true if your data property is of type `GetTopRoomInfoRsp`, then your object surely can't be of type

```
{
  loaded: false;
  loading: boolean;
  error: any;
  data: null;
}
```

This is called Type narrowing in typescript. I suggest looking it up in [TS docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) and also [Discriminating Unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions).